# save each data in loop as text file in matlab

Tags: matlab, loops, text-files

I am doing an operation to get a matrix M_T. This matrix is to be saved into a text file. And this text file is to be again utilized as the primary data file. This has to be repeated for 100 times. Also in the end I want to save all the data in the 100 text files generated into a single text file named final_result.txt. I am not able to figure out how to save the different text files in different names within the loop. I tried by writing the following code. But it is showing errors.

```
for k=1:100

fid = fopen('data1.txt'); 
A =  textscan(fid, '%f %f %f ') ;
%read the file
a = A{1};
b = A{2};
c = A{3};
p=[a b c];
p_t=p.';
M=rotationMatrix*p_t;
M_T=M.';


fid = fopen('data1.txt', 'wt');
fprintf(fid,' %f\t %f\t %f\n',M_T);
fclose(fid);

textfilename = ['result' num2str(k) '.txt'];
fid1 = fopen('result'k '.txt', 'wt');
fprintf(fid1,' %f\t %f\t %f\n',M_T);
fclose(fid1);

end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
textfilename = ['result' num2str(k) '.txt'];
fid1 = fopen(textfilename, Write);
...
```

this should generate a separate file `resultk.txt` where k = 1,...,100.
Also, you are opening the input file twice but only closing it once. I think it would be better to close the file when you open it for reading before again opening it for writing.
If this doesn't solve the problem, try posting the specific error messages you get.

To output all files to a master file, do this before the loop starts

```
fidresult = fopen('final_result.txt', Write);
```

then at each iteration

```
fprintf(fidresult,' %f\t %f\t %f\n',M_T);
```

then after the loop is finished

```
fclose(fidresult)
```

This should output your matrix at each iteration to the master result file in addition to creating an individual file for each loop iteration

Comment: thanks it solved the problem, but I also wanted to combine the data from all the 100 text files into a single text file, one after other in order.

Comment: Then just create the master file at the start, then each iteration write the matrix to that file also, before closing the file after your loop has finished

Comment: I have tried doing that but it is not saving the data in order.